# Yii mail() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, yii

How can I convert array to string?

```
$to=Person::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

I want to send an email to multiple email addresses.

```
mail($to,$model->subject,$model->body,$headers);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$to` only contains email addresses you could convert it to a string: `$to = implode(', ', $to);`

Comment: I tried $to = implode(', ', $to);I'm getting PHP Error Object of class Person could not be converted to string.

Comment: That means $to is not an array of email addresses (strings) but an array of Objects (of type Person). Those Persons probably have a method to get the email address, and you need to do that first:
`$to=Person::model()->findAll($criteria);
$emails = array();
foreach($to as $p) {
  $emails[] = $p->getEmailAddress(); // or whatever it's called...
}
mail(implode(',', $emails), $model->body, $headers);`

Comment: Please explain about $p->getEmailAddress().

Comment: In the above code snippet $to is an array of Persons (objects of class Person). In the foreach loop each item in the array is, in turn, assigned to $p. So $p always refers to one object of class Person. I just assume that such object has a method to obtain its email address. That method could be called `getEmail()` or `getEmailAddress()` or something else. You should check the implementation of Person to find out exactly. If I assume the method is called `getEmailAddress` then `$p->getEmailAddress()` gets the email address for that person. You may need `$p->getEmail()` or yet something else.

Comment: ok...I'm retreiving email addresses by using `CDbCriteria`.`$criteria=new CDbCriteria;$criteria->condition="status=1";$criteria->select="email";$to=Person::model()->findAll($criteria);` I'm still not clear about converting array of object (of type Person) to string.

Comment: I got it. I created a method to get email address and it worked! Thank you for your help!